# Is there any c++ user defined function to store the specified string and display the size of store

Tags: c++, memory-management, size

I need to display the size of the store after every operation like delete, find, etc.,

To do that, the requirement is this: memory should be allocated either for a new string or only on expansion and should never be reallocated if the string is being reduced/contracted either through trim or deleting a part of it. The extra memory should be available in the class for re-use.

For example – the user added a string ‘ABC’, so 4 bytes would be allocated. Further, he added a string ‘FGH’, the allocation is now 7 bytes. Now he finds and deletes the string part ‘FG’, the string should contract but the allocation should be still 7 bytes, so if the user now adds up to 2 characters there should not be any re-allocation requirement and must not use string data type.

I would appreciate it if anybody can help me. I'm totally stuck here.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `capacity()` method of a class. The example for vector [is this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity).

Comment: @llualpu Perhaps even [std::string::capacity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity)

Comment: Thanks, @llualpu and  Nathan, but I must not use string data type so I used char. Does vector support char?

Comment: @Toughcookie, absolutely yes, vector does support char: `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @llualpu I have tried using the below example but the size of the store is displaying 8 even added more characters still it displayed me 8, above I have added my code can you please look into it and suggest me anyway that is possible. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Toughcookie Make sure that you set the character '\0' appropriately in `Delete`. I don't think I can see it in that function's code. Also, IMO, the readability of your code could benefit from reducing that staggering amount of blank lines. Also, is this some kind of course assignment? If not, I suggest you use `std::string`, since it most likely implements all that you've written in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

By using `std::vector<char>`'s method `capacity` you can achieve what you want. For example, this program pushes the characters of a string into a vector by using `push_back` (this is done like this just to see the capacity grow). Then removes the elements by doing `pop_back`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print_after_add(const std::vector<char>& v, char k) {
    std::cout
        << "Added '" << k << "'. "
        << "Capacity: " << v.capacity() << ". "
        << "Size: " << v.size()
        << '\n';
}

void print_after_remove(const std::vector<char>& v, char k) {
    std::cout
        << "Removed '" << k << "'. "
        << "Capacity: " << v.capacity() << ". "
        << "Size: " << v.size()
        << '\n';
}

int main() {
    const std::string input_string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    std::vector<char> v;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input_string.size(); ++i) {
        v.push_back(input_string[i]);
        print_after_add(v, input_string[i]);
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input_string.size(); ++i) {
        v.pop_back();
        // uncomment this line to see the capacity go down
        //v.shrink_to_fit();
        print_after_remove(v, input_string[input_string.size() - i - 1]);
    }
}
```

The output with `v.shrink_to_fit()` commented is (in my laptop):

```
Added 'A'. Capacity: 1. Size: 1
Added 'B'. Capacity: 2. Size: 2
Added 'C'. Capacity: 4. Size: 3
Added 'D'. Capacity: 4. Size: 4
Added 'E'. Capacity: 8. Size: 5
Added 'F'. Capacity: 8. Size: 6
Added 'G'. Capacity: 8. Size: 7
Added 'H'. Capacity: 8. Size: 8
Added 'I'. Capacity: 16. Size: 9
Added 'J'. Capacity: 16. Size: 10
Added 'K'. Capacity: 16. Size: 11
Added 'L'. Capacity: 16. Size: 12
Added 'M'. Capacity: 16. Size: 13
Added 'N'. Capacity: 16. Size: 14
Added 'O'. Capacity: 16. Size: 15
Added 'P'. Capacity: 16. Size: 16
Added 'Q'. Capacity: 32. Size: 17
Added 'R'. Capacity: 32. Size: 18
Added 'S'. Capacity: 32. Size: 19
Added 'T'. Capacity: 32. Size: 20
Added 'U'. Capacity: 32. Size: 21
Added 'V'. Capacity: 32. Size: 22
Added 'W'. Capacity: 32. Size: 23
Added 'X'. Capacity: 32. Size: 24
Added 'Y'. Capacity: 32. Size: 25
Added 'Z'. Capacity: 32. Size: 26
Removed 'Z'. Capacity: 32. Size: 25
Removed 'Y'. Capacity: 32. Size: 24
Removed 'X'. Capacity: 32. Size: 23
Removed 'W'. Capacity: 32. Size: 22
Removed 'V'. Capacity: 32. Size: 21
Removed 'U'. Capacity: 32. Size: 20
Removed 'T'. Capacity: 32. Size: 19
Removed 'S'. Capacity: 32. Size: 18
Removed 'R'. Capacity: 32. Size: 17
Removed 'Q'. Capacity: 32. Size: 16
Removed 'P'. Capacity: 32. Size: 15
Removed 'O'. Capacity: 32. Size: 14
Removed 'N'. Capacity: 32. Size: 13
Removed 'M'. Capacity: 32. Size: 12
Removed 'L'. Capacity: 32. Size: 11
Removed 'K'. Capacity: 32. Size: 10
Removed 'J'. Capacity: 32. Size: 9
Removed 'I'. Capacity: 32. Size: 8
Removed 'H'. Capacity: 32. Size: 7
Removed 'G'. Capacity: 32. Size: 6
Removed 'F'. Capacity: 32. Size: 5
Removed 'E'. Capacity: 32. Size: 4
Removed 'D'. Capacity: 32. Size: 3
Removed 'C'. Capacity: 32. Size: 2
Removed 'B'. Capacity: 32. Size: 1
Removed 'A'. Capacity: 32. Size: 0
```

Notice that the capacity is not affected by the `pop_back`s.

It would be nice that you learnt about the method `shrink_to_fit`, so you can learn a bit more how C++ vectors work. If you uncomment the line `v.shrink_to_fit()`, the output of the program is:

```
Added 'A'. Capacity: 1. Size: 1
Added 'B'. Capacity: 2. Size: 2
Added 'C'. Capacity: 4. Size: 3
Added 'D'. Capacity: 4. Size: 4
Added 'E'. Capacity: 8. Size: 5
Added 'F'. Capacity: 8. Size: 6
Added 'G'. Capacity: 8. Size: 7
Added 'H'. Capacity: 8. Size: 8
Added 'I'. Capacity: 16. Size: 9
Added 'J'. Capacity: 16. Size: 10
Added 'K'. Capacity: 16. Size: 11
Added 'L'. Capacity: 16. Size: 12
Added 'M'. Capacity: 16. Size: 13
Added 'N'. Capacity: 16. Size: 14
Added 'O'. Capacity: 16. Size: 15
Added 'P'. Capacity: 16. Size: 16
Added 'Q'. Capacity: 32. Size: 17
Added 'R'. Capacity: 32. Size: 18
Added 'S'. Capacity: 32. Size: 19
Added 'T'. Capacity: 32. Size: 20
Added 'U'. Capacity: 32. Size: 21
Added 'V'. Capacity: 32. Size: 22
Added 'W'. Capacity: 32. Size: 23
Added 'X'. Capacity: 32. Size: 24
Added 'Y'. Capacity: 32. Size: 25
Added 'Z'. Capacity: 32. Size: 26
Removed 'Z'. Capacity: 25. Size: 25
Removed 'Y'. Capacity: 24. Size: 24
Removed 'X'. Capacity: 23. Size: 23
Removed 'W'. Capacity: 22. Size: 22
Removed 'V'. Capacity: 21. Size: 21
Removed 'U'. Capacity: 20. Size: 20
Removed 'T'. Capacity: 19. Size: 19
Removed 'S'. Capacity: 18. Size: 18
Removed 'R'. Capacity: 17. Size: 17
Removed 'Q'. Capacity: 16. Size: 16
Removed 'P'. Capacity: 15. Size: 15
Removed 'O'. Capacity: 14. Size: 14
Removed 'N'. Capacity: 13. Size: 13
Removed 'M'. Capacity: 12. Size: 12
Removed 'L'. Capacity: 11. Size: 11
Removed 'K'. Capacity: 10. Size: 10
Removed 'J'. Capacity: 9. Size: 9
Removed 'I'. Capacity: 8. Size: 8
Removed 'H'. Capacity: 7. Size: 7
Removed 'G'. Capacity: 6. Size: 6
Removed 'F'. Capacity: 5. Size: 5
Removed 'E'. Capacity: 4. Size: 4
Removed 'D'. Capacity: 3. Size: 3
Removed 'C'. Capacity: 2. Size: 2
Removed 'B'. Capacity: 1. Size: 1
Removed 'A'. Capacity: 0. Size: 0
```

Notice now that the capacity decreases by `1` after every `pop_back`.